# Python Google CustomerLicense "Not authorized to access the application ID"

Tags: python, licensing, google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to check if the user has installed my marketplace app

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
import json
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build

fname = 'my-creds.json'
scope = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license'
]
applicationId='12345678'
customerId='mydomain.com'

json_key = json.load(open(fname))

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)

http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())

appsmarket = build('appsmarket', 'v2', http=http_auth)

response = appsmarket.customerLicense().get(applicationId=applicationId, customerId=customerId).execute()
print response
```

I have created a service account in the same project as my app in Google console.

But I keep getting

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/customerLicense/471879773528/ashish%40noodletools.com?alt=json returned "Not authorized to access the application ID">
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you add service account to your domain's authorized API clients in security section?
Look at **Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account** here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

To delegate domain-wide authority to a service account, an administrator of the Google Apps domain must complete the following steps:

1. Go to your Google Apps domain’s Admin console.
2. Select Security from the list of controls. If you don't see Security listed, select More controls from the gray bar at the bottom of the page, then select Security from the list of controls. If you can't see the controls, make sure you're signed in as an administrator for the domain.
3. Select Show more and then Advanced settings from the list of options.
4. Select Manage API client access in the Authentication section.
5. In the Client Name field enter the service account's Client ID.
6. In the One or More API Scopes field enter the list of scopes that your application should be granted access to.
7. Click Authorize.

Your application now has the authority to make API calls as users in your domain (to "impersonate" users). When you prepare to make authorized API calls, you specify the user to impersonate.